# How can I getting value of 8 neighbor of a image as the third dimension in Numpy

Tags: opencv, numpy

Given an 2d image data, for every pixel P1, how can I get the following 3d array out of it?

```
P9  P2  P3
P8  P1  P4
P7  P6  P5
```

img[x,y,:] = [P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, P2]

without using forloop, just numpy operation (because of performance issue)

Comment: How do you want to handle the boundary elements?

Comment: I want a 3D array, and boundary can be either set to 0 or shrink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach with `zeros` padding for boundary elements and using `NumPy strides` with the built-in [`scikit-image`'s `view_as_windows`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_windows) for efficient sliding window extraction -

```
from skimage.util import view_as_windows as viewW

def patches(a, patch_shape):     
    side_size = patch_shape
    ext_size = (side_size[0]-1)//2, (side_size[1]-1)//2
    img = np.pad(a, ([ext_size[0]],[ext_size[1]]), 'constant', constant_values=(0))
    return viewW(img, patch_shape)
```

Sample run -

```
In [98]: a = np.random.randint(0,255,(5,6))

In [99]: a
Out[99]: 
array([[139, 176, 141, 172, 192,  81],
       [163, 115,   7, 234,  72, 156],
       [ 75,  60,   9,  81, 132,  12],
       [106, 202, 158, 199, 128, 238],
       [161,  33, 211, 233, 151,  52]])

In [100]: out = patches(a, [3,3]) # window size = [3,3]

In [101]: out.shape
Out[101]: (5, 6, 3, 3)

In [102]: out[0,0]
Out[102]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [  0, 139, 176],
       [  0, 163, 115]])

In [103]: out[0,1]
Out[103]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [139, 176, 141],
       [163, 115,   7]])

In [104]: out[-1,-1]
Out[104]: 
array([[128, 238,   0],
       [151,  52,   0],
       [  0,   0,   0]])
```

If you want a `3D` array, you could add a `reshape` at the end, like so -

```
out.reshape(a.shape + (9,))
```

But, be mindful that this would create a copy instead of the efficient strided based views we would get from the function itself.

Comment: Thank you, you probably want to type "//" instead of "/" in the second line of the function